# MonadError section in "All about monads"

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm now really confused about the Error monad in which "All about monads" describes.

It claims the definition of Error monad as

```
class (Monad m) => Monaderror e m | m -> e where
  throwError :: e -> m a
  catchError :: m a -> (e -> m a) -> m a
```

And one of the instance is Either e.

```
instance MonadError (Either e) where
  throwError = Left
  (Left e) `catchError` handler = handler e
  a        `catchError` _       = a
```

Here is what I don't understand.
The MonadError class take two type parameters, and (Either e) takes one, how is this
instantiation work? Is this because the functional dependencies? I still don't get it.

AND! I've runed this code in GHCi(with -XFunctionalDependencies, -XMultiParamTypeClasses) didn't compile! What's is this piece of code, anyway?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just a typo, the instance should be

```
instance MonadError e (Either e) where
  throwError = Left
  (Left e) `catchError` handler = handler e
  a        `catchError` _       = a
```

with two type parameters, as you expected.

`Either e` is the monad, and `e` is the corresponding error type.

Comment: Also, in the first line of the class definition, I think "class (Monad m) => Monaderror..." should be "class (Monad m) => MonadError..."

Comment: @mhwombat, Yeah, that's my typo O_O